# Ionic Programmatic Tab Population

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-tabs

I'm attempting to create a tab for each section of a menu.

So I have the following data structure:

```
[
  { name: 'Wines', contents:[...] },
  { name: 'Ciders', contents: [...] },
  { name: 'Beers', contents:[...] }
]
```

What I want is some sort of ngFor that would produce a tab for each element in the array above.

I haven't seen anything online for this and can't seem to solve it myself.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let tabs = [{name:'Wines', contents:[...]},
 {name:'Ciders', contents: [...]},
 {name:'Beers', contents:[...]}
];

<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [root]="tab.name"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

This should work if `tab.name` is a page that has an `@IonicPage` decorator where the class-name equals the `name` property of your tab object. Example:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyPage {
}
```

Then `tab.name` has to be **MyPage**.

Please note that setting a string as root of a tab utilizes lazy loading to set the root page of the tab. So you should probably read the following articles by the ionic-team if you are not familiar with it:

- [Part 1](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/)
- [Part 2](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/)